# How to change background of body based on current date with javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do I change the background of my `body` based on season with javascript?

I have following code:

```js
// Return the southern hemisphere season for a date
// If no date provided, uses current system date
function getSeason(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;  // Adjust to be indexed from 1
  var day = d.getDate();
  var seasons = ['summer','autumn','winter','spring'];

  // Do silly seasons here
  if (mon == 12) {
    if (day >= 13 && day <= 27) {
      return 'spring';
    }
    if (day >= 28 && day <= 31) {
      return 'spring';
    }
  }

  // If wasn't a silly season, do others
  mon = Math.floor((mon % 12) / 3);
  return seasons[mon];
}
```

```css
.spring { background: green; }
.summer { background: red; }
.autumn { background: brown; }
.winter { background: aquamarine; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.body.classList.add(getSeason())
});
</script>

<body class="getSeason">
Hello There
</body>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried to solve this problem.

Comment: So you got a nice function that returns the current season. Now where in your code are you trying to change the CSS?

Comment: Sorry, I know just a little bit of HTML and CSS. I have no experience with JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a class to body: `document.body.classList.add(getSeason())`

Comment: You need to add the function to document ready as well: check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fajhbkLw/12/)